# How to use tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax correctly

Tags: python, tensorflow

currently I play a little bit around with tensorflow to create a better understanding of machine learning an tensorflow itself. Therefore I want to visualize the methods (as much as possible) of tensorflow. To visualize max_pool I loaded an image and perform the method. After that I displayed both: input and output image.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = cv2.imread('lena.png')
image_tensor = tf.expand_dims(tf.Variable(image, dtype=tf.float32), 0)

#output, argmax = tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax(image_tensor, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name='pool1')
output = tf.nn.max_pool(image_tensor, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name='pool1')

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
session = tf.Session()
session.run(init)

output = session.run(output)

session.close()

image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()

output = cv2.cvtColor(output[0], cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(255-output)
plt.show()
```

Everything works fine and I get this output (as expected)

[image: image (input)]
[image]

Now I wanted to test the method `tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax` to get the argmax of the pooling operations. But if I uncomment the line

`output, argmax = tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax(image_tensor, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name='pool1')`

Python crashes with

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'MaxPoolWithArgmax' with these attrs
>        [[Node: pool1 = MaxPoolWithArgmaxT=DT_FLOAT, Targmax=DT_INT64, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1]]]

I don't have an idea which argument is wrong because every argument should be correct ([tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/nn.html#max_pool_with_argmax)) ...

Does anyone know what went wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a look at [the implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/bc64f05d4090262025a95438b42a54bfdc5bcc80/tensorflow/core/kernels/maxpooling_op.cc#L672), it appears that the [`tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/nn.html#max_pool_with_argmax) is only implemented for GPU. If you are running the CPU-only build of TensorFlow, then you would get an error of the form `"No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'MaxPoolWithArgmax' with these attrs ..."`.

(This seems like a place where the documentation and the error message could be improved.)

Comment: is the any alternative to run max_pool_with_argmax on CPU?